# Does being rocked in a cradle or sleeping on a ship improve sleep quality in the same way?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, learning, sleep, children

As we all know, mothers tend to rock the child in a cradle or in their hands.
Is there any research finding that supports the claim that rocked babies sleep better than ones only held still in their mothers' hands? (My anecdotic assumption.)
And if this holds, then is it true that sleeping on a ship (constantly moving bed) improves sleep quality?

Comment: Common enough shared assumption to make a good question here! However, I think you can easily leave the "ship" part out and wait to see which answers you get. The tags also seem ... random.  You do state _any_ research would fit your answer, so seems odd you added specifics. And why "learning"? 

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Well, to be honest, I wanted to fill in all 5 possible tags which could be any related. I am anyway more interested in how learning happens during sleep, but I did not want to mix different questions into one. When I am trying to find info about good sleep, most is about what to eat before sleep, how older people sleep differently than younger, or how sleep is altered in ill people, but about how the external world movement affect sleep I did not really find anything exact (apart from blogs telling me that boats yachts and ships are good to sleep in:)

Comment: But now indeed I tried to look up on Google Scholar rather than googling all the way, and found interesting articles about that even adults can fall into sleep easier when rocked, and also sleep deeper! :) But still, I am curious for other answers

Comment: I will write an answer soon where I describe what I found there :)